# Cumulative value of an edge or node attribute while descending an igraph object

Tags: r, igraph, edges, cumulative-sum

I have an `igraph` object `g` made from dataframe `df`:

```
df <- data.frame(c(0,1,2,2,4), c(1,2,3,4,5), c(0.01, 0.03, 0.05, 0.01, 0.02))
colnames(df) <- c('parent_id', 'id', 'dt')
g <- graph_from_data_frame(df)
```

Edges are made between `parent_id` and `id`.

```
> g
IGRAPH DN-- 6 5 -- 
+ attr: name (v/c), dt (e/n)
+ edges (vertex names):
[1] 0->1 1->2 2->3 2->4 4->5
```

Change in thickness `dt` is the edge attribute. This can be thought of as the change in thickness between a 'parent' and 'child' iceberg (this is my problem/project).

```
list.edge.attributes(g)
[1] "dt"
```

to visualize:

```
plot(g, edge.label=E(g)$dt)
```

Example of nodes and edge attribute `'dt'`

[image]

**I need to find the cumulative sum of `dt` at each node while descending from parent to child.**

When thinking in terms of 'ancestor', 'parent' and 'child' nodes, this is equivalent to getting the cumulative sum of `dt` for all ancestors at each 'child' node.

Cumulative `dt` assigned as edge attribute, anticipated outcome example

[image]

It is OK if these cumulative values are assigned as new node or edge attributes, or another form of output.

I have tried 1) the `network.aggregate` function in the `RNewsflow` package & 2) the `aggregate` function in the `data.tree` package.

Thank you in advance for interest and  help.

Comment: `distances` might be useful. `distances(g, "0", weights=E(g)$dt)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can indeed use data.tree for this. Though `Aggregate` will sum up from children towards parent, and from what I understand, you want to do the opposite. So the following will work:

```
library(data.tree)
df <- get.data.frame(g, what = "edges")
dtr <- FromDataFrameNetwork(df)
dtr$dtcum <- 0
dtr$Do(function(node) node$dtcum <- node$parent$dtcum + node$dt, filterFun = isNotRoot)
print(dtr, "dt", "dtcum")
```

This will print out as:

```
          levelName   dt dtcum
1 0                   NA  0.00
2  °--1             0.01  0.01
3      °--2         0.03  0.04
4          ¦--3     0.05  0.09
5          °--4     0.01  0.05
6              °--5 0.02  0.07
```

Comment: Thank you! This works  - I'm now working to implement this on an igraph object with multiple nodes that represents `roots`.